# Data Modelling tool for Neo4j

Tags: database, graph, neo4j

Is there any tool to design graph data base ?
I know best tool is 'Pencil' and 'Paper' but apart from this ?

Thanks
AmitAggarwal

Comment: Can you write what you want? Is it web interface for user's drawing graph?

Answer (score 0):

UML Class modeling provides a good fit, so IBM's Rational product will work. There is a close affinity between classes and graph models. Tools like ERwin and Powerdesigner can also be used but you have to use them a little more loosely than they were originally intended for. They were intended for logical and physical data modeling but if you are looking for the visual model mostly, then they would work as well.